# How can I make this function more elegant

Tags: function, haskell, parametric-polymorphism

I have the function:

```
wrap :: Text -> [Text] -> Text
wrap x = intercalate "" . map ((<> x) . (x <>))
```

The purpose of which is to wrap each element of a list with a given string and join them all together.

The brackets around the first argument to map annoy me, and so does the use of "". So I wonder is there a more elegant (or generic, I guess) way to express this function?

Comment: You could use `foldMap f` instead of `intercalate "" . map f`. Note that `intercalate ""` is equivalent to Data.Text.concat.

Comment: Ah, that is nice. Now I have `wrap x = foldMap $ (<> x) . (x <>)`

Comment: With no imports. `wr x str = [ x++s++x | s <- str]` and `concat.wr "!" $ ["one","two","fix"]`

Comment: I always forget I can use list comprehension on strings, very cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Copied from my comment so the question can be marked as answered.)

You could use `foldMap f` instead of `intercalate "" . map f`. Note that `intercalate ""` is equivalent to Data.Text.concat.

Answer (score 2):

Just to put my hat in the ring... Since the pattern is

```
xexxexxex
```

(where the `e`s are placeholders for elements of the original list), another way you can build this output is by putting two `x`s between each element, and wrapping the bookends manually. So:

```
wrap x es = x <> intercalate (x <> x) es <> x
```

One small but nice feature of this rewrite is that for input lists of length n, this will incur only n+2 calls to `(<>)` rather than 3n-1 as in theindigamer's answer.

Comment: I did have something like this originally, but I found it not so pleasing. Thanks though.

Comment: I like your idea, but I'm concerned that the final `<>` could be a bit of an efficiency problem because `intercalate` isn't a "good producer" for list fusion. I think the easiest way to work around that is likely to use `foldr` directly.

Comment: @dfeuer There are no lists being produced here anyway, only `Text`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, ah, silly me. So does that mean some sort of builder is required?